# Write numpy structured array using savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

I faced a problem with writing structured array in txt file.
Having an output file (*outfile*) opened, I use the following numpy function:

```
np.savetxt(*outfile*, ***recarray***, fmt=['%s','%-7.4f','%-7.4f','%-7.4f'])
```

The ***recarray*** is like [ (b'H', 0.9425, 0.1412, 7.1414) ... (b'N', 1.0037, 4.0524, 6.8000) ], where the first element has `numpy.bytes_` type and others are `numpy.float64`.

An error message appears while writing this recarray in file:

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

So, what is the easiest way to put this array in file? Maybe there is another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using Python 3.0. In this case, you have to specify before `'%s'` the letter b like this : `b'%s'`

In Python3, the default string type is unicode, so you have use the extra b to mark byte strings.

Your script should be :

```
np.savetxt(*outfile*, ***recarray***, fmt=[b'%s','%-7.4f','%-7.4f','%-7.4f'])
```

Don't forget to write `wb` when you are opening your .txt file :

```
file = open('workfile.txt','wb')
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. But now there is another question. Is it possible to turn b'H' just to single H symbol? And also I don't understand why even setting **delimiter='\n'** it doesn't write the elements of recarray in file like this, i.e. single element in one line:
H  0.9425  0.1412  7.1414
...
N  1.0037  4.0524  6.8000
but all of them are written in line. The same problem with header, which is also printed in line.

Comment: If the first problem is solved, please set my answer as solution to the others users.
You should open a new question because your second one is kind different to the first one.

Comment: dear @Andromedae93, thank you again for your help. I prepared a separate question just as you suggested